# How to return to method, android;

Tags: android, onclick, return

I've got a questions. I have an OnClick method. So user clicks on button it randomly gens image. So when he finds the similar image and clicks on it I need to do OnClick from the beginning.

---

No, there is a point:
1.User click on 1 image
2. It generates the second image
3. 3 different images is already on the desk and he needs to find the proper image.

Ok, 
If a = b, then do the onClick method for image 1.

Comment: Try callOnClick() or performClick() for your button object - if I understand you right.

Comment: Do you need a clickable image generated which listens for click event? Question is not clear enough. Please be specific. Sample code should help.

Comment: If a button is clicked twice then the listener is called twice

Comment: I would suggest you edit the question and make it clearer. Do you want a button to generate images? If so adding onclicklistener is enough. If you want users to be able to click on the image, then using ImageButton is an alternative. And what do you mean by similar image? Similar to what image?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the user to click on image to generate new image, then you can use ImageButton for this. Add OnClickListener to this button and change the image in that listener.

[Tutorial here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-example/)